# How to implement sign in with xbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, xbox, xbox-live

I used microsoft graph api to implement signin but with that I am not getting xbox details of the user. How to get xbox details.

I want the xbox id of the user to pass to the endpoint in xboxapi.com to get xbox details of the user.

Response I am getting from microsoft graph api is in the image. I need xbox details.[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the following documentation Microsoft Graph does not support Xbox.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview

The documentation here should help you get what you are looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/introduction-to-xbox-live-apis

Thank You,
Xbox Live Forum Moderator

Comment: Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.

Comment: The docuementation shows only code implemented in c++. Is there any sample code to implement in javascript ?